# Looping a specific segment of a movie using AVPlayer - always seeks back to beginning

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a video that is about 12 seconds long.  Seconds 5-10 are loopable.

I want to play the video from the start the first time, then continue to loop over seconds 5-10 afterwards indefinitely.

However when I try, the video just jumps back to the beginning again.
Am I doing something wrong here?  The video is H.264 mp4 format.

Here's a snippet of code I use: (the update function gets called every frame)

```
-(void) update:(double)timeDelta
{
    if ( !m_player ) {
        return;
    }

    CMTime time = m_player.m_player.currentTime;
    if ( CMTimeGetSeconds(time) > 10.0f ) {
        [m_player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5.0f, time.timescale)];     
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Most players will only seek to I pictures (Intra pictures). It may be that your clip only has a I picture in the begining and another one after 5 seconds. Check that. If you can re-encode, then re-encode with I pictures inserted every 1 second to allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably seeking to a keyframe, if the keyframe interval on that particular video is greater than 5 seconds.

Try either adjusting the way the video is encoded such that you are able to get a keyframe at the 5 second mark or use

```
[m_player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5.0f, time.timescale) toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero];
```

Note that if you do this, the decoder will have to decode those 5 seconds of video before resuming playback at the point you want, so you may end up with a brief delay in your loop.